# RSQLite does not create local database

Tags: rsqlite

Reprex:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = "test.sqlite")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)
dbListTables(con)
[1] "mtcars"
dbDisconnect(con)
```

When I come back:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = "test.sqlite")
dbListTables(con)
character(0)
```

I thought `dbConnect` should create a database if none exists. I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Both code blocks create a database on a temporary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a **local** database you still need to supply parameters specific to your machine. This fixed the issue for me:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),
                  user = 'root',
                  password = '',
                  dbname = 'test.sqlite',
                  host = 'localhost')
```

This is documented poorly if you do not have much understanding of SQLite databases. It seems a database was only being created in memory. Maybe someone else can expound on this as I think warnings would help guide users in this situation.

Comment: I don't think `user`, `password` and `host` help much here. `dbname` is the parameter to set, instead of `path`. See `?RSQLite::"dbConnect,SQLiteDriver-method"` .